# replace \n with blank but keep \r\n using sed/tr

Tags: bash, sed

My input looks like:

```
Line 1\n 
More Line 1\r\n
Line 2\n 
More Line 2\r\n
```

I want to produce

```
Line 1 More Line 1\r\n
Line 2 More Line 2\r\n
```

Using sed or tr. I have tried the following and it does not work:

```
sed -e 's/([^\r])\n/ /g' in_file > out_file
```

The out_file still looks like the in_file. I also have an option of writing a python script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sed '/[^\r]$/{N; s/\n/ /}' in_file
```

#### How it works:

- `/[^\r]$/`

  This selects only lines which do **not** have a carriage-return before the newline character.  The commands which follow in curly braces are only executed for lines which match this regex.
- `N`

  For those selected lines, this appends a newline to it and then reads in the next line and appends it.
- `s/\n/ /`

  This replaces the unwanted newline with a space.

#### Discussion

When sed reads in lines one at a time but it does not read in the newline character which follows the line.  Thus, in the following, `\n` will never match:

```
sed -e 's/([^\r])\n/ /g'
```

We can match `[^\r]$` where `$` signals the end-of-the-line but this still does not include the `\n`.

This is why the `N` command is used above to read in the next line, appending it to the pattern space after appending a newline.  This makes the newline visible to us and we can remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file | sed 's/\r/\r\n/g'
```

It will print:

```
Line 1 More Line 1\r\n
Line 2 More Line 2\r\n
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works. I accepted the earlier answer as it was posted first.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ if(!/\\r\\n$/){ sep=""; sub("\\\\n","",$0) } else sep=ORS; printf "%s%s",$0,sep }' file
```

The output (literally):

```
Line 1 More Line 1\r\n
Line 2 More Line 2\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -z -i.bak 's/\n/\r\n/g' filename
```